# How to Edit localStorage array in php loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, mysqli

I have localStorage array with name "totalPackage". As per my project requirement I have to change localStorage Array data with PHP loop.

**Here is Coding**

```
if (mysqli_multi_query($con,$sql)){
    do{
        if ($result=mysqli_store_result($con)){
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                echo $row["totalcost"]." ";
            } else {
                //echo "0"; 
            }           
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        } 
    }while (mysqli_next_result($con));
}
```

When you see **echo $row["totalcost"]." ";** statement i want to remove localStorage array element.

Comment: Do you mean JavaScript's `localStorage`?!

Comment: Do you want to remove $row['totalcost'] from localstorage, right?

Comment: `localStorage.removeItem("totalPackage");`?